# Is there a way to declare a successive string literal union in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to declare a string literal union type: "10" | "11" | ... "99".

I came up with a workaround, but didn't work

```js
const arr = Array.from({
  length: 90
}, (_, i) => i + 10) as const; // expected arr type is readonly [10, 11, ..., 99]
// If above works, then
type NumberToString<T extends number> = `${T}`;
type Successive = NumberToString<typeof arr[number]>;
```

I wonder if there is a way to quickly define "10" to "99" on top of type level?

Comment: You can't use runtime code to generate compile-time static annotations…

Comment: @deceze Well, then is there a way to declare the expected type? I haven't found any alternative for `for` loop in Typescript, it seems like Typescript lacks the ability to express  loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be possible in next (4.5) version of TypeScript where [type instantiation depth limit should be increased](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/45711)

```
type _NextValue<From, LastValue, R extends any[]> = LastValue extends number 
    ? R['length'] 
    : R['length'] extends From ? From : null

/**
 * Fill array with `null` placeholders until index `From`
 * Then append array length as a member until getting to `To` length
 * Example: `_Values<5, 11>` will result in `[null, null, null, null, null, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`
 */

type _Values<From, To, R extends any[] = [], LastValue = null> = R['length'] extends To ? R : 
    _Values<
        From, 
        To, 
        [...R, _NextValue<From, LastValue, R>], 
        _NextValue<From, LastValue, R>
    >

/**
 * Exclude nulls and convert to strings
 */
type NumbersToStrings<T extends Array<number | null>> = `${NonNullable<T[number]>}`;

type N10_99 = NumbersToStrings<_Values<10, 100>> // "10" | "11" | "12" | "13" | "14" | "15" | ... | "99"
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.0-beta#code/C4TwDgpgBA+gchAHsAagQwDYFcIB4BiATgPYC2ANFADJoDOqmOlASlEsBAHYAmtUanEAG0AugD4oAXmp0G2aOy68onLKQBGEQgFgAUFANQA-FGZCA5Bi4BzYAAtzIvYagAuUxaudbDkW2RKfERkxlDBpG4qWBgYenoA9ABUic6JYQCWMfyEhGggUADu6fZQAAaqMaVQYBhoAMYQdsQY3Fp8WJzAmVDpPEhl4aWpUAAqdlz8YJA82bn5Xj78fGhQpBAaWlAdXRhQ1hDAXd5QwMRlI8RVC-bDAKKIaKQ1EO6lMOjytLgArJQAjH8xFUillCBBaNFgD1OGUhBUMJR4YjogiojFkeioL8oAA2SgAdkoAA5KABOf4ABhEQ30iXicV0oEgsA+OC+4UoFxY-g4PGWglEUigokoNHorOg0nhEmkZksNnsjh5gVGZxMrFczkM70Y4NwWpcBg5BsNXJNLiEADprcxKPB2BKCCQKDJxbqWGIRORzdqEMhHRzXXImKYxCaw7oEsk7og6thWmiMPzuFA6sROAA3LRQ05QeiEXrWWipemM8DQOBqTSEWgXADKwAL3i+I2VfKgAEEcnlcKoNoQoAAfRNiGVlAAkAG84OnKzE0OorLgRnCq1pxABfUoAbgZTIrfwpMFJpKFlf7teIDabRdwOs+uEPlIpo6g8XiUAARIfP0OvwDf2Hb8ACZAP-ABmMDvwAFigv5vjA61LT-T8T0-PdyygOBvhgQ8zzXGt60bQsvnvNkfn+QEJHfL8EJQnEoPxKCiSg0k4IpdDIy4vR9zCYgzmkMi9WxAFqI-VdMSRRMMVRKTsTxKBCSgEkoHJKBDycXQgA)

Comment: Your idea of filling array with `null` is so nifty, thanks. When TS release 4.5 stable, I'll upgrade my code base to 4.5

Comment: It seems like on type level, we can only use recursion to accomplish the "loop-like" task? For me, 10 to 99 literal can simply be achieved by a loop

Comment: Yes, no loops on type level, at least for now

Answer (score 0):

I found a different approach to solve this question, while @Aleksey L. fills
`Tuple` with beginning `null`s and records last pushed value, my approach is to use a `TempTuple` whose length is `Start` and grows as `ResTuple` grows.

```js
type AddOne<T extends number, Tuple extends unknown[] = []> = 
    Tuple["length"] extends T ? [1, ...Tuple]["length"] : 
        AddOne<T, [1, ...Tuple]>; 

/** fill tuple to a fixed length */
type FillTuple<T extends number, Tuple extends unknown[] = []> = 
    Tuple["length"] extends T ? Tuple : 
        FillTuple<T, [1, ...Tuple]>; 

/** TempTuple is meant to grow as ResTuple grow */
type RangeTuple<Start extends number, End extends number, ResTuple extends unknown[] = [], TempTuple extends unknown[] = FillTuple<Start>> =
    TempTuple["length"] extends AddOne<End> ? ResTuple : 
        RangeTuple<Start, End, [...ResTuple, `${TempTuple["length"]}`], [1, ...TempTuple]>;

{
    type _ = RangeTuple<10, 99>[number];
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggJnA8gOwgHgCpQgD2BZOAZymQFcBbAIwgCcAaKDMsAG2l30JLOQGtkAewDuyANoBdKAF4okgHwyoAWABQUDUxbsxAInbIA5sAAWuqZwLEmUAPxyAjIwB0r5mwgS9B42akAuFXVNEPgkVExGMScoV2d3dgl5AG4gtQB6ACpMqAAzAEtWVihgbWhgQSgAQzz8nAg4KB9TKEz0tVBIKAAxQtYE9CxLblJKGgYtD2w8Kx5%20IVFJJQUlNRCB7wJfc2muayx7AahAtZDNXqKByMcXNzKk1LUM7KYICjAj-JIKCCrkYBKlUMtBE1RIACUIEQjsDQW0OuBoOC-oYIFcAMrAKq0AHDazkah0RgAUUIu1mo0JE0h0LK5JGvAEInEUlkkkYGDeHzpeLmTMWrJ6fQxWJx8kU0lOGk57w2%20i2ph2vNgCBQ6FJcEU9hpRxOwTOUGRRjRZTQmOxwBJhCicR1ZUYAAMACQAbxl3I8myMiokAF8HRIojE4u6Bg8nqoXVKSoioAB9JRG1FXBwABkYAE4M-IxATxhJkmpfUA)